# Getting Same Values For Two Different Keys in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, android-database

i am creating an app in which different payments modes are there so for card payments and cheque payments i have created two different activities in which i am getting details from user and save the data into shared Preferences and then app returns back to the activities where other details are also there and then user can save the data on a button click.This data gets saved into Sqlite Database.
My problem is when i am selecting card payment its getting stored properly but the same value also getting stored at cheque No aswell into the sqlite database.Inshort the value of card payment is getting copied into cheque no column by default.

below is my code for Card payment Activity :

```
public class CardNo extends Activity {

String bankname;
String cardno;
int chq;
TextView textView1, textView2;
EditText editText1, editText2;
Button btn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.creditdebit);

    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bankname);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cardno);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveData();

            Intent card = new Intent(CardNo.this, EnterAmount.class);
            startActivity(card);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

private void saveData() {

    bankname = editText1.getText().toString();
    cardno = editText2.getText().toString();


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Bank Name", bankname);
    editor.putString("Card No", cardno);
    editor.apply();


}
}
```

Now code for cheque payment Activity :

```
     public class Cheque extends Activity  {
String bankname1;
String chequeno;
int chq;
TextView textView1,textView2;
EditText editText1,editText2;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cheque);


    textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv11);
    textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv12);
    editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bankname1);
    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.chequeno);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn11);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveData();

            Intent cheque = new Intent(Cheque.this, EnterAmount.class);

            startActivity(cheque);
            finish();

        }
    });

}

private void saveData() {

    bankname1 = editText1.getText().toString();
    chequeno = editText2.getText().toString();


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Bank Name", bankname1);
    editor.putString("Cheque No", chequeno);
    editor.apply();

}
}
```

Now the code of the activity where i am retrieving the data from shared preferences  and storing the data into sqlite.

```
     public class EnterAmount extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Intent intent;
    Button save;
    Spinner spinnerPayment, spinnerCategory;
    EditText etamt, etbdgt, et_get_other;
    String date, sBdgt, budget, bankname, cardno, chequeno;
    String sAmt;
    String spinnerItemSelectedPayment;
    String spinnerItemSelectedCategory;
    // String category;
    int amt;
    int date2;
    TextView caategories, tv_cat;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.enteramount);

            save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsaveDb);
            caategories = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCaategories);
            etamt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmount);
            etbdgt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etbudget);

            spinnerCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);

            spinnerPayment = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.payment_spinner);

            List<String> sCategory = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] categories = {"Food", "Bills",
                    "Travel", "Entertainment", "Office Stationary",
                    "Medical Expenses", "Fuel"
            };

            sCategory.add("Food");
            sCategory.add("Office Stationary");
            sCategory.add("Bills");
            sCategory.add("Travel");
            sCategory.add("Entertainment");
            sCategory.add("Medical Expenses");
            sCategory.add("Fuel");

            ArrayAdapter<String> sc = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sCategory);
            spinnerCategory.setAdapter(sc);


            List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] paymentMode = {"Cash", "Credit/Debit Card", "Cheque", "NetBanking"};
            l.add("Cash");
            l.add("Credit/Debit Card");
            l.add("Cheque");
            l.add("NetBanking");
            ArrayAdapter<String> sp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, l);
            spinnerPayment.setAdapter(sp);

            save.setOnClickListener(this);


            spinnerCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                           View selectedItemView, int pos, long id) {
                    spinnerItemSelectedCategory = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
                            .toString();



                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    spinnerItemSelectedCategory = "Food";
                }
            });

            spinnerPayment.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                           View selectedItemView, int pos, long id) {
                    spinnerItemSelectedPayment = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                    if (spinnerItemSelectedPayment.equals("Cheque")) {
                        Intent cheque = new Intent(EnterAmount.this, Cheque.class);
                        cheque.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(cheque);


                    } else if (spinnerItemSelectedPayment.equals("Credit/Debit Card")) {

                        Intent card = new Intent(EnterAmount.this, CardNo.class);
                        card.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(card);


                    }
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    spinnerItemSelectedPayment = "Cash";

                }
            });


            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy-HH:mm:ss ");

            date = sdf.format(c.getTime());


            int yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            int dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            String s = yy + "" + (mm < 10 ? ("0" + mm) : (mm)) + ""
                    + (dd < 10 ? ("0" + dd) : (dd));

            Log.e("datechange", s);

            date2 = Integer.parseInt(s);
            Log.e("integer2", "hello" + date2);

        }


        @Override
        public void onBackPressed () {

            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();

        }

    private void vibrate(int ms) {
        ((Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(ms);
    }


    private void loadSavedPreferences() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        budget = sharedPreferences.getString("Budget", " ");

getSharedPreferences(mypreference,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bankname = sharedPreferences.getString("Bank Name", "Not Applicable");
        cardno = sharedPreferences.getString("Card No", "Not Applicable");
        chequeno = sharedPreferences.getString("Cheque No", "Not Applicable");


    }

    private void removeSavedPreferences() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove("Bank Name");
        editor.remove("Cheque No");
        editor.remove("Card No");
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bsaveDb: {

                savePreferences("Budget", etbdgt.getText().toString());
                loadSavedPreferences();



                sAmt = etamt.getText().toString();


                Log.e("category", "Hello" + sAmt);
                try {
                    amt = Integer.parseInt(sAmt);
                    Log.e("amt is", "" + amt);

                } catch (Exception e) {


                }


                DbClass dc = new DbClass(this);
                dc.open();

                if (amt == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please insert the amount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {


                    dc.categoryDetailsInsert(amt, spinnerItemSelectedCategory, date, spinnerItemSelectedPayment, date2, bankname, cardno, chequeno);
                    dc.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    amt = 0;
                    etamt.setText("");
                    etbdgt.setText(budget);
                    removeSavedPreferences();


                }

                break;

            }
        }
    }
     }
```

i am attching a screenshot of sqlite database and you can see bank name is getting stored properly but cardno and cheque no is always same with respect to payment.[Screenshot Of Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1dxO.png)

Comment: Use different key other than "Bank Name","Cheque No"  for SharedPreferences in cheque payment as they are already used in  Card payment Activity

Comment: @voidpointer there is no problem with bank name , it is getting stored properly and i have not defined "Cheque No" inside card payment activity. see i have attached the screenshot in question just now see the last 4-5 entries only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually above code is Fine the Problem was in the code where i was retrieving code from the database i inserted the same index number for the two different columns. so i was getting same values for cheque no and debit card number.

Answer (score 0):

Attach your keys to the context tag to prevent override of values.
like:
String TAG = "ContextName or ActivityName";

then on saving do:

pref.put(TAG+key, "value");

Comment: and how to retrieve these values in another activities ?